# How can I improve the execution speed of my script

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, perl, awk

I have a file containing about 15 million records. Below is a sample of the data

```
99001597,555555555555,3211,Njro_Kaniani,test,NORTH,Yes,Yes,Yes,smart,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,IN2017,OnePlus,1,N/A,Yes,Yes,Yes,N/A
99001679,555555555555,1756,Bnju_HTT,Salam,,Y,RAD,Yes,Yes,Yes,smart,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,BE2012,OnePlus,1,N/A,Yes,Yes,Yes,N/A
99001680,555555555555,1108,Temoni_Kiara,Salam,,Y,RAD,Yes,Yes,Yes,smart,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,BE2028,OnePlus,1,Google,Yes,Yes,Yes,N/A
99001683,555555555555,1604,Blue_Bay,Nzindo,,Y,COAST,Yes,Yes,Yes,smart,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,BE2011,OnePlus,1,N/A,Yes,Yes,Yes,N/A
99001683,555555555555,1820,Sgerea_Makuka,Salaam,,N,RAD,Yes,Yes,Yes,smart,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,BE2011,OnePlus,1,N/A,Yes,Yes,Yes,N/A
99001683,555555555555,1184,Makka,Salaam,,Y,RAD,Yes,Yes,Yes,smart,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,BE2011,OnePlus,1,N/A,Yes,Yes,Yes,N/A
99001683,555555555555,1381,Leaders_Club,Salam,,Y,RAD,Yes,Yes,Yes,smart,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,BE2011,OnePlus,1,N/A,Yes,Yes,Yes,N/A
99001683,555555555555,1037,Mbez,Salam,,Y,RAD,Yes,Yes,Yes,smart,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,BE2011,OnePlus,1,N/A,Yes,Yes,Yes,N/A
99001683,555555555555,1041,Ngano,Salam,,Y,RAD,Yes,Yes,Yes,smart,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,BE2011,OnePlus,1,N/A,Yes,Yes,Yes,N/A
99001683,555555555555,1313,Kichangani,Salam,,Y,RAD,Yes,Yes,Yes,smart,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,BE2011,OnePlus,1,N/A,Yes,Yes,Yes,N/A
99001684,555555555555,4975,Nyugusu Campp2,Test,test,Yes,Yes,Yes,smart,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,BE2026,OnePlus,1,Google,Yes,Yes,Yes,N/A
99001684,555555555555,1041,Ngano,Salam,,Y,RAD,Yes,Yes,Yes,smart,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,BE2026,OnePlus,1,Google,Yes,Yes,Yes,N/A
99001684,555555555555,1420,Airport_Macro,Salaam,,Y,RAD,Yes,Yes,Yes,smart,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,BE2026,OnePlus,1,Google,Yes,Yes,Yes,N/A
99001684,555555555555,3147,Technical_Nzoti,test,ORTH,Yes,Yes,Yes,smart,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,BE2026,OnePlus,1,Google,Yes,Yes,Yes,N/A
99001684,555555555555,4488,Lumala,Mwnza,,Y,Nyeka,Yes,Yes,Yes,smart,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,BE2026,OnePlus,1,Google,Yes,Yes,Yes,N/A
99001684,555555555555,4975,Nyarugusu Campp2,Kigoma,,Y,Nyeka,Yes,Yes,Yes,smart,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,BE2026,OnePlus,1,Google
```

I am using the below script to count the occurrence of lines matching certain conditions. The problem is this script is very slow. I get about 200 output lines in a day.
Currently, my program will read the 15 million record file 36,000 times.  This is very inefficient (slow!!).  How can I rework my script to just read the very large file just one time?

Desired output

```
1037,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
1041,0,0,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2
1108,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
1184,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
1313,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
1381,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
1420,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
1604,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
1756,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
1820,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
3147,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1
3211,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1
4488,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
4975,0,0,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,0,0,1
```

The IDs_file file contains about 3000 records each a 4 digit number

```
while read i
do

twog=$(cat combined_marketing_sadm_report.csv|awk -v src=$i -F, '{if ((($10 == "Yes")||($10 == "No")) && ($3 == src) && ($9 == "No")&& ($11 == "No")) print $0;}'|wc -l)

threeg=$(cat combined_marketing_sadm_report.csv|awk -v src=$i  -F,'{if (($3 == src) &&($9 == "Yes")&& ($11 == "No")) print $0;}'|wc -l)

fourg=$(cat combined_marketing_sadm_report.csv|awk -v src=$i -F,'{if (($11 == "Yes") && ($3 == src)) print $0;}'|wc -l)
lte2100=$(cat  combined_marketing_sadm_report.csv|awk -v src=$i  -F, '{if (($13 == "Yes") &&  ($3 == src)) print $0;}'|wc -l)
lte800=$(cat  combined_marketing_sadm_report.csv|awk -v src=$i  -F, '{if (($14 == "Yes") &&  ($3 == src)) print $0;}'|wc -l)
lte700=$(cat  combined_marketing_sadm_report.csv|awk -v src=$i  -F, '{if (($15 == "Yes") &&  ($3 == src)) print $0;}'|wc -l)
lte1800=$(cat  combined_marketing_sadm_report.csv|awk -v src=$i  -F, '{if (($16 == "Yes") &&  ($3 == src)) print $0;}'|wc -l)
lte2600=$(cat  combined_marketing_sadm_report.csv|awk -v src=$i  -F, '{if (($17 == "Yes") &&  ($3 == src)) print $0;}'|wc -l)
lte900=$(cat  combined_marketing_sadm_report.csv|awk -v src=$i  -F, '{if (($18 == "Yes") &&  ($3 == src)) print $0;}'|wc -l)
threeg2100=$(cat  combined_marketing_sadm_report.csv|awk -v src=$i  -F, '{if (($24 == "Yes") &&  ($3 == src)) print $0;}'|wc -l)
threeg900=$(cat  combined_marketing_sadm_report.csv|awk -v src=$i  -F, '{if (($25 == "Yes") &&  ($3 == src)) print $0;}'|wc -l)
volte=$(cat  combined_marketing_sadm_report.csv|awk -v src=$i  -F, '{if (($23 == "Yes") &&  ($3 == src)) print $0;}'|wc -l)

echo $i,$twog,$threeg,$fourg,$lte2100,$lte800,$lte700,$lte1800,$lte2600,$lte900,$threeg2100,$threeg900,$volte>>Raw_data_for_report.csv
done < IDs_file
```

---

Comment: `I have a file containing about 15 million records` Don't use the shell for this task. Instead explain what the goal is. What is the desired result/output ?

Comment: Is the 15 million records file called `IDSs_file` or `combined_marketing_thing`? What's in the other file?

Comment: Approach 1: import your data into a SQLite or other database, add appropriate indexes, and query that. Approach 2: rewrite to only run awk once inside the loop, not 12 times (and get rid of the Useless Uses Of Cat and wc too, and move the output redirection *outside* the loop) shoot, you can probably do it all in awk in a single pass over both files, no shell needed.

Comment: 15 million records are in combined_marketing_sadm_report.csv and IDS_file contains about 3000 records each a 4 digit number

Comment: You can iterate over the csv file, grouped by src and calculate the figures. That would require a single pass over the csv. Then you "merge" it with your ID file.

Comment: one `awk` script; 1st file (`IDs_file`) gets loaded into array, for every record in 2nd file (`combined_marketing_sadm_report.csv`) check if `$3 in array` and if so, increment a set of counter arrays based on the various field checks (eg, `if (...) twog[ID]++; if(...) four[ID]++; ...`); this would require a *single* pass through each file;  the `END {...}` block contains a `for` loop to print the arrays to stdout

Comment: Have a look at [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716/118235)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution: put all your loops in one awk program:

```
#! /usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {
    FS=OFS=","
    if (src=="") {
        exit
    }
    split(src,arr_src,",")
    for (i in arr_src) {
        src=arr_src[i]
        twog[src]=threeg[src]=fourg[src]=lte2100[src]=lte800[src]=lte700[src]=lte1800[src]=lte2600[src]=lte900[src]=threeg2100[src]=threeg900[src]=volte[src]=0
    }
}
{
    for (i in arr_src) {
        src=arr_src[i]
        if ($3 == src) {
            if (($10 == "Yes" || $10 == "No") && $9 == "No" && $11 == "No") twog[src]++
            if ($9  == "Yes" && $11 == "No") threeg[src]++
            if ($11 == "Yes") fourg[src]++
            if ($13 == "Yes") lte2100[src]++
            if ($14 == "Yes") lte800[src]++
            if ($15 == "Yes") lte700[src]++
            if ($16 == "Yes") lte1800[src]++
            if ($17 == "Yes") lte2600[src]++
            if ($18 == "Yes") lte900[src]++
            if ($24 == "Yes") threeg2100[src]++
            if ($25 == "Yes") threeg900[src]++
            if ($23 == "Yes") volte[src]++
        }
    }
}
END {
    for (i in arr_src) {
        src=arr_src[i]
        print src,twog[src],threeg[src],fourg[src],lte2100[src],lte800[src],lte700[src],lte1800[src],lte2600[src],lte900[src],threeg2100[src],threeg900[src],volte[src]
    }
}
```

Call:

```sh
./counter.awk -v src=1037,1041,4975 combined_marketing_sadm_report.csv
```

**UPDATE**

If your `src` values are in a file, the script (`counter-v2.awk`) became:

```sh
#! /usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {
    FS=OFS=","
}
FNR == NR {
    i++
    arr_src[i] = $0
    next
}
FNR == 1 {
    for (i in arr_src) {
        src=arr_src[i]
        twog[src]=threeg[src]=fourg[src]=lte2100[src]=lte800[src]=lte700[src]=lte1800[src]=lte2600[src]=lte900[src]=threeg2100[src]=threeg900[src]=volte[src]=0
    }
}
{
    for (i in arr_src) {
        src=arr_src[i]
        if ($3 == src) {
            if (($10 == "Yes" || $10 == "No") && $9 == "No" && $11 == "No") twog[src]++
            if ($9  == "Yes" && $11 == "No") threeg[src]++
            if ($11 == "Yes") fourg[src]++
            if ($13 == "Yes") lte2100[src]++
            if ($14 == "Yes") lte800[src]++
            if ($15 == "Yes") lte700[src]++
            if ($16 == "Yes") lte1800[src]++
            if ($17 == "Yes") lte2600[src]++
            if ($18 == "Yes") lte900[src]++
            if ($24 == "Yes") threeg2100[src]++
            if ($25 == "Yes") threeg900[src]++
            if ($23 == "Yes") volte[src]++
        }
    }
}
END {
    for (i in arr_src) {
        src=arr_src[i]
        print src,twog[src],threeg[src],fourg[src],lte2100[src],lte800[src],lte700[src],lte1800[src],lte2600[src],lte900[src],threeg2100[src],threeg900[src],volte[src]
    }
}
```

File `IDSs_file`:

```
1037
1041
1108
1184
1313
1381
1420
1604
1756
1820
3147
3211
4488
4975
```

Execute like this (**Warning**: Files order is very important):

```sh
./counter-v2.awk IDSs_file combined_marketing_sadm_report.csv
```

Output:

```
1037,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
1041,0,0,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2
1108,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
1184,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
1313,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
1381,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
1420,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
1604,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
1756,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
1820,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
3147,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1
3211,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1
4488,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
4975,0,0,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,0,0,1
```

Comment: Thanks, @arnaud.  But how do I iterate for all 3k src values contained in the IDSs_file file?

Comment: @Raziel, I have updated my response for two input files

Comment: Thanks a lot @Arnaud Valmary